# Scanner Optimization

Tags: java

I have completed a java assignment. The target is to build a java app using eclipse IDE to `add.userAccount(String id, String name, String email)` in to a file.

I am curious about optimization. I put that code into a loops **(such as:**

`for(int times = 0, time < 10000; time++) 
add.userAccount(String id, String name, String email);`)

but it takes alot of time **(5 minutes)**. I use FileInputStream and FileOutputStream. (to input and output) Is anyone here suggest me the way to **optimize this code**?
Here is my code in Main test, i create a test case with 10000 times:

```
String path = "/home/thinhnv/user.txt";
        Account account = new Account(path);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            Random rd = new Random();
            int rd1 = rd.nextInt(10);
            int rd2 = rd.nextInt(10);
            int rd3 = rd.nextInt(10);
            int rd4 = rd.nextInt(10);
            String  ten= "" + rd1 + rd2;
            String maTK = "Thinh" + rd1 + rd2 + rd3 + rd4;
            String sdt = "" + rd1 + rd2 + rd1 + rd2 + rd1 + rd2 + rd1 + rd2 + rd1 + rd2;
            String pass = sdt;
            User user = new User(maTK, pass, ten, sdt);
            account.add(user);
        }
```

and here is my code for more details:

```
    public void add(User user) {// user i create in main
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                getUsersInforFromFile();// this method i open a file, read 
//data from this and take it in to List<User> users private property and// //end of this method i close input file
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println(" Error: getUsersInforFromFile: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            if (this.users.size() == 0) {
                writeUserToFile(user);
                System.out.println("signup successfully!");
                return;
            }
            if (this.users.indexOf(user) == -1) {
                writeUserToFile(user);// this method i open a file and write a data at append mode and then close this file
                System.out.println("signup successfully!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Account" + user.getMaTK() + " is already exist! Sign up failed");
            }
        }
```

Lastly, i use only methods : fineIn.read(), and fileOut.write() byte by byte. Is this make my programme run more slowly?

Comment: Are you opening and closing the file repeatedly? Show us your code.

Comment: Please paste your code then only someone can optimize it.

Comment: I have already edit for more detail. If you want to know more, comment here.

Comment: Opening, writing, and closing the file in order to write each user is horribly inefficient---specifically the opening.  Once you've opened the file, however, writing is fairly inexpensive.  If you know you will be writing multiple users, you'd do much better by providing a way of opening the output file _once_, then keep it open while writing out the users, and only close it once all the users were written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce number of write operations by creating large of chunks of data together, Opening and closing file stream takes time so try reduce that as well.

Comment: Ok. I will try to reduce openning and closing file stream

Comment: You are performing 1 read and 1 write operations for 10000 times. Use data structure to store information of the file and update it with data when you add new user, By that you will not require to check user from file. Reducing file read operation to just 1.

Comment: Also you chunk data together to reduce write operations as file is string you can easily do it.

Comment: if you guy have time plz see my full code here :
https://github.com/ThinhNgVhust/UserAccount.git
each time i read or i write i open the file. i store a line of data by String. I think it will be better for me to show you my full source to let you know. May be i can event more get advise about how to write code clean :)

Comment: We understood your issue, Just avoid reading and writing of file on every iterations

Comment: Hey guys. Sorry coz i make this post so bad in english grammar. I think one of the reason not only about open and close file too much time. It also a bout each time i add a User, i also check the id of user so it take time to compare id with the other user.